# Can't identify reason for BULK INSERT errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, bulkinsert, bcp

I'm trying to run this query (I also tried it without specifying FIELDTERMINATOR and ROWTERMINATOR). It's using a datafile that I am manually creating beforehand (not with bcp out).

```
BULK INSERT FS.dbo.Termination_Call_Detail
FROM 'C:\Termination_Call_Detail__1317841711.dat'
WITH
(
 FORMATFILE = 'C:\Termination_Call_Detail__update_TerminationCallDetailData.fmt',
 FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
 ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
)
```

The errors I'm getting:

> Server message number=4864 severity=16 state=1 line=1
>   server=USA109MSSQL1A
>   text=Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid
>   character for the specified codepage)
>   for row 1, column 9 (RouterCallKey).
>
> Server message number=4832 severity=16 state=1 line=1
>   server=USA109MSSQL1A
>   text=Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the
>   data file.
>
> Server message number=7399 severity=16 state=1 line=1
>   server=USA109MSSQL1A
>   text=The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)"
>   reported an error.
>   The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Server message number=7330 severity=16 state=2 line=1
>   server=USA109MSSQL1A
>   text=Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked
>   server "(null)".

I'm trying to get it working with just 1 row.

ASCII datafile:

```
611658275664    1                       5027    5001    5005    5010    2011-10-05 14:53:44     1317840824      240     2011-10-05 14:54:04     1317840844      150026  211     2       1       4480    21543   28      0       29      0       0       0       0       29      0       0                       0       IPT_Call        TAC_Rollover                                                                    424755/4        N       0       5030    5000    2865                    805336626                       2674794299      N                                               1       3       N       0               0
```

Hex dump of the datafile: http://pastebin.com/grnwQrdT

The format file: http://pastebin.com/WwSQvCGg

The table schema: http://pastebin.com/gFjp4xYy

This insert is using 66 columns; the table contains 84 columns. If I create a format file with bcp of the whole table, and a datafile of this same row, I can run this BULK INSERT QUERY without a problem.

Hex dump of a datafile created by bcp on the same row of data (with all the columns): http://pastebin.com/MpMk6iq4

I meticulously looked for any missing newlines or tab delimiters, but I cant find any. You can see on the hex dump of the datafile that everything looks properly delimited. I compared it to a datafile created by bcp and couldn't find any formatting differences.

I also cant imagine why its complaining about that particular field (RouterCallKey) - there are other fields above it in the format file that are the same type (like RouterCallKeyDay).

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldnt you know it, I figure it out right after I get frustrated enough to post the question.  There was a logical bug elsewhere in the code that created the datafile that was feeding this bulk insert query the wrong format filename.  It does work now.

Comment: Well, then I won't bother telling you the problem I found.   Glad you got it solved...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldnt you know it, I figure it out right after I get frustrated enough to post the question.  There was a logical bug elsewhere in the code that created the datafile that was feeding this bulk insert query the wrong form