# Bulk Insert using format file for varying number of columns between datafile and actual database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bulkinsert, bcp

This is the Schema for a table

```
Create table dbo.Project
(
ProjectID (int,not null)
ManagerID (int,not null)
CompanyID(int, not null)
Title (nvarchar(50),not null)
StartDate(datetime,not null)
EndDate(datetime,null)
ProjDescription(nvarchar(max))
)
```

I created a datafile called bob.dat from this table which has around 15 rows with the following bcp command

```
bcp "Select ProjectID,ManagerID,CompanyID,Title,StartDate from CATS.dbo.Project" queryout "C:\Documents\bob.dat" -Sbob-pc -T -n
```

Also a format/mapping file called bob.fmt was created using the following bcp command

```
bcp CATS.dbo.Project format nul -f C:\Documents\bob.fmt -x -Sbob-pc -T -n
```

Then i created a copy of the table Project.

```
Create table dbo.ProjectCopy
(
ProjectID (int,not null)
ManagerID (int,not null)
CompanyID(int, not null)
Title (nvarchar(50),not null)
StartDate(datetime,not null)
EndDate(datetime,null)
ProjDescription(nvarchar(max))
```

)

What i want to do now is use the bob.dat and bob.format file to populate this table ProjectCopy using the following Bulk Insert statement.

```
BULK INSERT CATS.dbo.ProjectCopy
 FROM 'C:\Documents\bob.dat' 
WITH (FORMATFILE = 'C:\Documents\bob.fmt',
 LASTROW=5,
 KEEPNULLS,
  DATAFILETYPE='native');
  GO
 SELECT * FROM CATS.dbo.ProjectCopy
 GO
```

So basically the data file does not contain any data for the columns EndDate and ProjDescription. I want these two columns to be remained as null. Unfortunately i get the
following error when i run the bulk insert statement.

```
 Msg 4863, Level 16, State 4, Line 2
 Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 1, column 6 (EndDate).
 Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
 The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. 
 The provider did not give any information about the error.
 Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
 Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

 (0 row(s) affected)
```

Anyone got any clue how this could be fixed?
just to inform you all i have already been to this sections and the solution provided there
didn't work out for me.
[BULK INSERT with inconsistent number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601941/bulk-insert-with-inconsistent-number-of-columns),
[Can't identify reason for BULK INSERT errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7667397/cant-identify-reason-for-bulk-insert-errors?rq=1),
[BULK INSERT with inconsistent number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601941/bulk-insert-with-inconsistent-number-of-columns)

Comment: In the column EndDate is not allowed NULL values. Try to change the NOT NULL on NULL

Comment: Hi Alexander nicely spotted! Thank you :).  I changed it to Null and i am still getting the same error.

Comment: This would be much more gracefully handled in SSIS or a .net app. I'd typically go with a streamreader and add nulls when the fields aren't available. Tim Mitchell has a nice alternative for those without .net experience here: http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/timmitchell/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=9

Comment: Awesome link. Thank you very much brian :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, for a creating a datafile called bob.dat you need to add two columns: EndDate and ProjDescription. In addition, for the bulk copy operation using Unicode-characters must be added the argument -W.
Example:

```
bcp "Select ProjectID,ManagerID,CompanyID,Title,StartDate, NULL AS EndDate, NULL AS ProjDescription from CATS.dbo.Project" queryout "C:\Users\Pawan\Documents\bob.dat" -Sbob-pc -T -n -w
```

The original format file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="NCharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t\0" MAX_LENGTH="24"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="NCharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t\0" MAX_LENGTH="24"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="NCharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t\0" MAX_LENGTH="24"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="NCharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t\0" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="Cyrillic_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="NCharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t\0" MAX_LENGTH="48"/>
  <FIELD ID="6" xsi:type="NCharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t\0" MAX_LENGTH="48"/>
  <FIELD ID="7" xsi:type="NCharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\0\n\0" COLLATION="Cyrillic_General_CI_AS"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="ProjectID" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="ManagerID" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="CompanyID" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="Title" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="StartDate" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="6" NAME="EndDate" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="7" NAME="ProjDescription" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

But you want a way to fill the data only upto StartDate. Therefore, this file needs to be changed:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="NCharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t\0" MAX_LENGTH="24"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="NCharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t\0" MAX_LENGTH="24"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="NCharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t\0" MAX_LENGTH="24"/>
  <FIELD ID="4" xsi:type="NCharTerm" TERMINATOR="\t\0" MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="Cyrillic_General_CI_AS"/>
  <FIELD ID="5" xsi:type="NCharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\0\n\0" MAX_LENGTH="48"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="ProjectID" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="ManagerID" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="CompanyID" xsi:type="SQLINT"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="4" NAME="Title" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="5" NAME="StartDate" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Comment: yes I know that if i add the data for the EndDate and ProjDescription in the datafile, it works. This is tried and tested. However i am looking to make the process more flexible by leaving out the last two columns. If you know a way to fill the data only upto StartDate that would be awesome.Think about it in future there may be additional columns added to the table in that case would be possible to use the same data and format file?

Comment: @Sike12 Ok.The answer was updated with a new information, read please

Comment: Yes something i tried before as well. i get the following error message when i use your format file. Msg 7339, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
OLE DB provider 'BULK' for linked server '(null)' returned invalid data for column '[BULK].StartDate'.

(0 row(s) affected)

Comment: For a creating a data file is necessary to use -w argument: bcp "Select ProjectID,ManagerID,CompanyID,Title,StartDate, ProjDescription from CATS.dbo.Project" queryout "C:\Users\Pawan\Documents\bob.dat" -Sbob-pc -T -n -w

Comment: yes i used -w argument. how come you have projDescription in your select query? Can you double check please?

Comment: Oh. Sorry it's a typo. bcp "Select ProjectID,ManagerID,CompanyID,Title,StartDate from CATS.dbo.Project" queryout "C:\Users\Pawan\Documents\bob.dat" -Sbob-pc -T -n -w

Comment: yes this is what i exactly did and i still got error message saying "Msg 7339, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
OLE DB provider 'BULK' for linked server '(null)' returned invalid data for column '[BULK].StartDate'.

(0 row(s) affected)" .. Does it work on your machine?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37893/discussion-between-sike12-and-alexander-fedorenko)